# western digital external hard drive write protected windows 7

Tags: external, hard-drive

Unable to add new folders and files to external hard drive after unlocking it using proprietary software "unlocker.exe" app.

Comment: It would be nice if someone could recommend where this question and answer belongs since I already tried the "LifeHacks" thread...  I'm aware this isn't code related... Although it does involve utilizing CMD in Windows.

Answer (score 0):

go to start search and type cmd, right click on the returned cmd.exe and select "run as administrator" an elevated cmd prompt will open.

This is an example that I did on my computer, make sure the external hdd is plugged in, then run these cmds (we are using diskpart) , you will need to recognize your external hdd in this case it was disk 5.

Code: Microsoft Windows [Version 6.0.6000] Copyright (c) 2006 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\windows\system32>diskpart

Microsoft DiskPart version 6.0.6000 Copyright (C) 1999-2007 Microsoft Corporation. On computer: VISTATEST

DISKPART> list disk

Disk ### Status Size Free Dyn Gpt

Disk 0 Online 233 GB 1177 KB Disk 1 No Media 0 B 0 B Disk 2 No Media 0 B 0 B Disk 3 No Media 0 B 0 B Disk 4 No Media 0 B 0 B Disk 5 Online 298 GB 2000 KB

DISKPART> select disk 5

Disk 5 is now the selected disk.

DISKPART> list volume

Volume ### Ltr Label Fs Type Size Status Info

Volume 0 I Removable 0 B No Media Volume 1 H Removable 0 B No Media Volume 2 F Removable 0 B No Media Volume 3 D DVD-ROM 0 B No Media Volume 4 J New Volume NTFS Partition 298 GB Healthy Volume 5 G Removable 0 B No Media Volume 6 C NTFS Partition 233 GB Healthy System

DISKPART> select volume 4

Volume 4 is the selected volume.

DISKPART> attr disk clear readonly

Microsoft DiskPart version 6.0.6000 NOTE:- you might simply receive here a message:- Disk attributes cleared successfully (this is fine)

VOLUME - Manipulate volume attributes.

DISKPART> attr volume clear readonly

Volume attributes cleared successfully.

DISKPART> detail disk

TOSHIBA MK3265GSX USB Device Disk ID: E9BE1B1F Type : USB Bus : 0 Target : 0 LUN ID : 0

Volume ### Ltr Label Fs Type Size Status Info

Volume 4 J New Volume NTFS Partition 298 GB Healthy
DISKPART> detail volume

Disk ### Status Size Free Dyn Gpt

Disk 5 Online 298 GB 2000 KB
Read-only : No Hidden : No No Default Drive Letter: No Shadow Copy : No Dismounted : No BitLocker Encrypted : No

Volume Capacity : 298 GB Volume Free Space : 35 GB

DISKPART> exit